# Make services not start automatically after reboot (as they require access to an encrypted partition)

Tags: ubuntu

I use Ubuntu Server 10.04. I more or less only want the server to be accessible over SSH after a reboot. I will then login and mount the encrypted partition myself, after which I start the services which uses it.

How would I go about setting something like that up?

(My first idea was to have everything except /boot in an encrypted LVM, but I never got logging in through SSH and mounting the LVM to work. Initramfs was a bit too complicated for me. Otherwise I think this would have been the best solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Services get started via entries in the various /etc/rc.d/ folders (they are named from rc1.d through to rc6.d). You will need to identify the services you don't want to start, and then change the Sxxservicename links (xx is a number between 01 and 99) to Kxxservicename. Please be aware that these changes may get overwritten when the relevant packages are upgraded. If you want to keep the changes, I would recommend changing the start/stop level definitions in /etc/init.d/servicename (each service has a script in that folder that actually executes the start/stop, and it also contains the default settings for the runlevels where the service should start and stop).

Then simply change the line for the encrypted partition in /etc/fstab to include the "noauto" option, which will prevent it from getting mounted at boot time. You can still mount it manually using the mount command.

**WARNING**: You must make sure that your boot process can complete without any of the data on the encrypted partition. Otherwise you are digging a big hole for yourself (and you'll need a live CD to get out of it).

Comment: Nope. Ubuntu changed away from old style init system to something called upstart some releases ago. Still hadn't time to look into this...

Comment: Then please explain to me why I have exactly those files and that boot behavior on my Ubuntu 10.04 box? Or, if you DO know more about how this works, provide a better answer to the OP, so we can all learn.

Comment: @SvenW, woflgangsz: This answer is not wrong, it's just incomplete. Upstart provides compatibility with system V init scripts, and the distribution handles ships with quite a few. This answer will take care of these, but if any of the upstart services require the encrypted filesystem, you also need to prevent them from starting at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Your distribution uses upstart to manage services, so you need to take care of both upstart services and “old-style” (system V) services.

For all upstart services that require the encrypted filesystem, edit the corresponding file in `/etc/init.d` and change `start on foo` to `start on (foo and encrypted-filesystems)` and `stop on bar` to `stop on (bar or runlevel [0126])`.

For all system V services that require the encrypted filesystem, rename the symbolic link `/etc/rc2.d/S??foo` to `/etc/rc2.d/K50foo`.

After you've mounted the encrypted filesystems, run the commands

```
initctl emit encrypted-filesystems
telinit 3
```

If you want to unmount the encrypted filesystems without rebooting, I think `telinit 2` will stop all the affected services with the scheme I've proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise using update-rc.d (check the man page) to disable startups in runlevel two since it should always "do the right thing".

It would also be a good  idea to put something in runlevel 2 to alert you, eg email, so it doesn't sit there unnoticed after an unexpected reboot.

Then ssh in, mount the crypt volume and init 3.

[Double check that it's still OK after package updates]